# what does cmd symbol `>&1` mean in the following?

Tags: cmd, console

Apologies if this is a dumb question, but what does the following command do on cmd?

```
test.exe 1> test.log 2>&1
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

On cmd (Windows) , this command do the following:

```
test.exe 1> test.log ...
```

The result of the standard output ( ... **1 >** ...) of the command `test.exe` is redirected to the `test.log` file

then

```
test.exe ... 2>&1
```

The result of the error output (... **2 >** ... )of the command `test.exe` is redirected to the first param file linked to the standard output ( **&1**) which is here the `test.log`  file.

If you want to redirect the standard output and the standart error to different file you just have to write something like:

```
test.exe 1> test.log 2> test_err.log
```

I hope I was clear and I made no mistake (:

It's quite the same on linux (1:STDOUT, 2:STDERR)